# State not updating inside recursion

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export default function App() {
  const [actionId, setActionId] = useState("");

  const startTest = async () => {
    const newActionId = actionId + 1;
    setActionId(newActionId);

    const request = {
      actionId: newActionId
    }

    console.log({ request });
    // const response = await api.runTests(request)

    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 4000));
    startTest();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <button onClick={startTest}>Start</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`request` actionId is always 1, though I changed it every 4 seconds.

I know `setState` is async, but it's weird that the state is not updated after 4 seconds.

Comment: Where is setInterval? SetTimeout will make its callback run only once.

Comment: `setState` is async and state is **constant** within a particular render of a component.

Comment: `Where is setInterval? SetTimeout will make its callback run only once`

Edited to recursion, we're calling the function again after 4 seconds.

Comment: @Yousaf I see, do you know how we can fix it, without moving it to `useEffect`.

Comment: One way would be to pass `newActionId` to `startTest()` as an argument. (Keep in mind that `newActionId` will is a string, so adding 1 to it will perform concatenation instead of addition)

Answer (score 1):

## Theory

A rendered React component contains functions that belong to **that** rendering. If these functions reference stale variables, this will affect the result. Search for **stale closures** to find out more about this. It is particularly easy to end up with stale closures when dealing with the traditional Javascript functions `setTimeout` and `setInterval` in React.

## So what's going on?

So on your first render, a particular instance of `startTest` exists. When you click the button, THAT instance of `startTest` runs. This instance of `startTest` contains a closure of `actionId` (by the way, why do you set `actionId` to `""` and then do addition to this? Would be more expected to start with 0 or do addition by `+ "1"`). When the state is set, React rerenders with `actionId` set to `"1"` and with a new version of `startTest` containing a closure where `actionId` is `"1"`. However, this function would only be triggered if you click the button anew. Instead, what happens is that the timeout from the first render triggers a new call to the *old* `startTest` from the first render. This timeout does not know that the component has rerendered and that there is a new version of `startTest` some place else with an updated closure of `actionId`. When the function is retriggered, it calculates the same value as the first time for `newActionId` and so we are trapped in a loop which only uses that very first instance of `startTest` containing a stale closure.

## How to solve it?

If you want to use timeouts and intervals in React, you gotta do it the React way. There are probably packages out there for this but if you want, you can change your example in a small way to make it work.

Instead of calculating the value of `newActionId`, you can supply a function to `setActionId` that takes the previous value as input:

```
setActionId(oldActionId => oldActionId + 1)
```

Now, since the previous value is always passed as input, the stale closure does not affect the outcome of the function and your example will work. However, I'm not sure about the design anyway because if a user hits the button again, you will have multiple timeouts running simultaneously which will cause a havoc in the long run. Nonetheless, if you want to make sure it works as expected, you could try it that way. If you could guarantee that the function would only be executed once, by restricting the button to only be pressed once, it would be a better design.

Good luck!